# Facebook video download from link

Tags: javascript, php, video

I want to download a Facebook video given the URL. When clicking on the link the video should be downloaded, but currently it opens a player and starts to play.

This image shows the Facebook video link:

[image]

This image shows how the video starts to play when clicking the link:

[image]

Answer (score -2):

if you have the fb video **actual url** and **not** the link page that view the video

you can add html5 **download attribute** to **< a >** tag

```
<a href="/path/to/myvideo.mp4" download>Download Video</a>
```